# AWS DynamoDB constraint on DynamoDBAttribute

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

I am trying to put a constraint on an attribute based on another attribute. If state is enabled then name has to have a value. How can I put a constraint? Using jdk 8

```java
@DynamoDBTable(tableName = "myTable")
public class MyTable {
    private String id;
    private State state;//Enabled or Disabled
    private String name;//if state is enabled then name property must have a value 

    public MyTable() {}

    public MyTable(final String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @DynamoDBHashKey
    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(final String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public State getState() {
        return state;
    }

    public void setState(final State state) {
        this.state = state;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(final String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This can be done only programatically:

```
if ("enabled".equals(myTable.getState()) {
    Objects.requireNonNull(myTable.getName(), "Name is missing while state is enabled");
}
mapper.save(myTable);
```

Comment: Thanks. But does dynamo have built in functionality for this? I prefer let the dynamo handle it

Comment: Not that I know of, but NoSql in general does not have good constraint support, as in Sql